# Find all vectors $x ∈ W$ that give the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $W$ be a vector space with $dim(W ) = 3$. Find all vectors $x ∈ W$ such that there exists
some basis α for which $[x]_α$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$

I'm stuck on this question here, not completely sure how to go about it. Here are the thoughts I've had so far:

$Ax = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$. So, I'm solving for some vector $x$ where all $A$ matrices give that matrix? Could $x$ be $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$? Do I need to somehow find $a$, the basis to solve this?

Would greatly appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: every vector other than the null vector.

If $x=0_W$, then the problem has no solution, since every coordinate of nuell vector with respect to any basis  is $0$.

And if $x\ne0_W$, just take two vectors $y$ and $z$ such that $B=\{x,y,z\}$ is linearly independent. Then $B$ is a basis of $W$ and$$x=1.x+0.y+0.z.$$

Comment: is this around the same idea as what I wrote for $x$?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use matrices here.